# Submit merged Debian package for inclusion in Ubuntu

Tags: packaging, development, debian

I'm [currently working to update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autogen/+bug/1098872) the version of `autogen` shipped with Ubuntu from `1:5.12-0.1ubuntu2` in the repositories to `1:5.17.1-1` in Debian. The merge has been completed on my computer and the commit made, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

For context, I did the following steps:

1. `bzr branch lp:ubuntu/autogen raring`
2. `bzr merge debianlp:experimental/autogen`
3. Resolve merge conflicts (there only was one in `debain/control` anyway)
4. `dch -i`
5. `bzr commit -m "New Debian version"`
6. `bzr builddeb -S --package-merge`

That last step resulted in a successful build, but now I'm a bit stumped as to my next move. The build produced the following files:

- build-area/autogen_5.17.1-1ubuntu1.debian.tar.gz
- build-area/autogen_5.17.1-1ubuntu1.dsc
- build-area/autogen_5.17.1-1ubuntu1_source.build
- build-area/autogen_5.17.1-1ubuntu1_source.changes
- build-area/autogen_5.17.1.orig.tar.xz

I know I can do `bzr push lp:~notgary/autogen/fix-1098872` and propose the merge that way, but I was wondering if there's anything I need to do with the files produced by the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about the [sponsorship process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SponsorshipProcess) on the wiki.

There's also more to merging than resolving conflicts. One should look at the differences between the Debian and Ubuntu packages, and figure out if each one is still needed and make sure that the ones that have, have been forwarded upstream.

Personally, I don't like reviewing merges done with bzr, it's really hard to figure out what's going on. So, I suggest generating a debdiff between `autogen_5.17.1-1.dsc` and `autogen_5.17.1-1ubuntu1.dsc`, and attaching that to the bug.

Stick your nose into `#ubuntu-motu` or `#ubuntu-devel` on IRC, people will be only to happy to guide you.